# How to use celluloid and ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, celluloid

I am using celluloid to perform some jobs in the background, some of the jobs are using the DB and for that I use the below code in a cell(actor):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
  User.find(123)
end
```

In some cases I have some services, which are queuing the DB but with some other logic in them. Can I send them to `...with_connection` or I need to wrap the call inside? Is there a better way of doing all this?

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
  SomeService.new(params).get_records
end

class SomeService
  def initialise(param)
    @params = params
  end

  def get_records
     some_logic
     ServicePersistenceModel.where(id: prams.id)
  end
end
```